# How to approximate the actual number of viewers of a video, given the number of viewers?

Tags: statistics

I have observed that the popular YouTube video,"Gangnam style" has about 2.2 billion views. This seems quite impossible to have that many viewers (since the world population is about 7 billion), and is possible that a viewer may have watched it multiple times. So, I'm wondered whether if it's possible to calculate (approximately) the actual number of viewers statistically.

P.S. Sorry if you have trouble understanding my topic/ English.

Comment: AFAIK, views are counted once per user, using different informations like cookies and IP address. 2.2 billions views means that 2.2 billions actual humans watch this video.

Comment: well, more than 1 human may have watched it simultaneously

Comment: Ok that's what I was thing too.. Thanks guys :)